# Please can someone remove the installation tag from the following question

Tags: support, retag-request

I can't remove the [installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/installation) from [debootstrap wants to remove target folder, why?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/237978/debootstrap-wants-to-remove-target-folder-why)

Please can someone else do this? I can't do it via the API either, which is how I realised.

Answer (score 5):

[setup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/setup) is actually a synonym of [installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/installation), you have to remove both. Presumably it didn't get merged when the synonymization happened.